# Верна ли моя интерпретация?

Tags: синтаксис, наклонение

> **Он был в ярости, ибо приди он раньше, застал бы ее с поличным.**

Я интерпретирую часть— *"приди он раньше, застал бы ее с поличным"*,— как условное предложение, где императив заменяется сослагательным наклонением (=если бы он пришел раньше...).

Вопрос: можно ли сказать, что это предложение осложняется причинными отношениями (tipo: *Он был в ярости, потому что не пришел раньше и не застал ее.)?*

Comment: Вы не интерпретируете, а трактуете, или рассматриваете, или считаете. Последнее лучше всего – скромненько и со вкусом. )

Answer (score 1):

Здесь два придаточных(СПП с двумя придат., соединёнными последовательно, но второе придаточное находится внутри первого):

[Он был в ярости], (ибо,(приди он раньше -условие), застал бы ее с поличным - причина).

Всё остальное в Ваших рассуждениях верно.

Comment: Людмила, так она и не говорила про структуру. Область интересов автора - условные (в широком смысле) предложения всякого рода. Она пытается сопоставить грамматику формы таких предложений с тем, что имеется в её родном языке с более жестким соотнесением формы и содержания, то есть синтаксиса и семантики фразы. Это неблагодарная задача изначально, но всё-таки речь не о СПП как таковом, тут со всякого рода модальностями и наклонениями надо разбираться, имхо.

Comment: Просто у меня подозрение, что автор  видит это как СПП с 1 придаточным - условным, осложнённым оттенком причины, а это 2 придаточных - условное и причинное.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду смешение с чем-то наподобие ***"Я был зол, ибо доехал бы быстрее, если бы не гололед"***? Вряд ли.  Даже мне трудно представить, что обстоятельство причины (да и любое другое), не являясь придаточным, могло бы передаваться глаголом в личной форме да еще с частицей "бы". Откуда у неё-то такие фантазии появятся?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Он был в ярости, ибо (2) (**приди он раньше, (3) застал бы ее с поличным**).

Можно изменить порядок предложений: Он был в ярости, так как (причина)  застал бы ее с поличным, если (условие) бы пришел раньше.

Нельзя сказать:  "это предложение осложняется причинными отношениями". Здесь два вида отношений: **причинные и условные.** Предложение 1 связано **причинными** отношениями с предложениями (2 + 3), они составляют единую структуру, а предложение 2 связно условными отношениями с предложением 3.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте вычленим из фразы ту часть, которая вас реально интересует.

**Приди он раньше, застал бы ее с поличным.**

Жто самодостаточная конструкция и она вся целиком является придаточным причины и первой части "он был в ярости". "Ибо" здесь синоним "потому(,) что".

> Я интерпретирую часть "приди он раньше, застал бы ее с поличным" как
>   условное предложение где императив заменяется сослагательным
>   наклонением. (=если бы он пришел раньше, ...)

По смыслу - да. По форме это особый грамматический тип наклонения - условный императив (он делится на условно-побудительный императив, условно-уступительный императив и собственно-условный императив; у нас скорее всего именно последний).

Смотрите здесь всё. 
http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2#48

http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

> Вопрос: можно ли сказать, что это предложение осложняется причинными
>   отношениями (tipo: Он был в ярости, потому что не пришел раньше и не
>   застал ее [с поличным].)?

Нет. Здесь смысл немного другой. В таком переложении можно предположить, что у героя ("у него") была ***цель*** застать героиню ("её") с поличным. Сама же фраза при этом переходит в категорию условно-побудительных с контрафактным условием (пришел бы раньше). *Купил бы тот лотерейный билет, по которому сосед миллион выиграл, стал бы богатым человеком.*

У нас же в исходной фразе нет такого значения. Непонятно, чем продиктоавана ярость: тем что не пришел раньше, или тем что мог застать (не желая этого).
*я был в растерянности, ибо приди раньше, не узнал бы того, что случилось сейчас* - в моем примере вообще нет эмоциональной составляющей. Её нет и в исходной условной фразе, "ярость" появляется только в грамматически главном предложении, источник её однозначно не интерпретируется, только по контексту.

(+++)

Вы сами себя еще не запутали?
Как вам уже говорили (и я в том числе), грамматика русских условных (сослагательных, побудительных и проч.) предложений не всегда прямо и однозначно определяет смысл. Иногда есть тонкости, которые иностранцу незаметны, а русский понимает не разбираясь в грамматике, но чаще все определяется контекстом - на уровне смыслового абзаца. Невозможно без специальной практики теоретически разобраться в том, в чем зачастую путаются сами носители.