# Приди он раньше, застал бы ее с поличным

Tags: синтаксис

Хотелось бы вернуться к старому вопросу:

[Верна ли моя интерпретация?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432581/%d0%92%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Если взять только эту часть предложения:

> Приди он раньше, застал бы ее с поличным.

Как правильно рассматривать это синтаксически?

Если я правильно интерпретирую, то нельзя считать это как сложноподчинённое предложение условия, потому что нет союза *если*, не так ли? Оно было бы сложноподчинённым предложением условия, если бы звучало *Если бы он раньше пришёл, застал бы её с поличным*, верно?
А если связь бессоюзная, то какой это тип предложения тогда? Как всегда, запуталась...

Спасибо!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, добрый день)  А мне показалось, что _как всегда_ тут не надо выделять запятой, вот как тут в конце: https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/kak-vsegda.html Я снова из любопытства спрашиваю) Хоть остальное вы оставили))

Comment: Здравствуйте, Юлия! [Вот](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=249109) похожий пример с запятой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Приди он раньше, застал бы ее с поличным.***

1) Это **бессоюзное сложное предложение** (БСП).

2) В БСП отношения между простыми предложениями выражаются **без помощи союзов.**

3) А как они выражаются? В данном БСП **условные отношения** между простыми предложениями выражены с помощью **сослагательного (условного) наклонения глаголов.**

Примечание: глагол *приди* имеет форму повелительного наклонения, но эта форма выражает сослагательное наклонение. https://studfiles.net/preview/5178226/page:24/

4) БСП с условными отношениями по значению соответствуют сложноподчиненному предложению (СПП) с союзом ЕСЛИ. **Это предложения-синонимы.**

Comment: Большое спасибо! я правильно понимаю: русская грамматика различает СПП причины/условия/уступки/цели etc. но для БСП нет таких особенных терминов? получается это просто БСП, в котором выражаются условные отношения?

Comment: Пожалуйста, всегда рада вам помочь. Вы правильно понимаете тему, я только немного дополню ее.  У БСП нет такой классификации, как у СПП, но они всё же условно делятся на две группы: однородного или неоднородного состава. Группа 1 соответствует сложносочиненным предложениям (ССП) с пропущенными сочинительными союзами или вообще без союзов, а группа 2 соответствует СПП с пропущенными подчинительными союзами.  И вот в группе 2 рассматриваются практически те же отношения: условия, причины, уступки и др.

Comment: понимаю! Sharon, вы солнышко! большое спасибо за помощь! =) God bless you!